# Error occured while updating the IDProvider

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I followed the Spring SAML quick start guide to enable SSO.
While updating the IdProvider with the sp metadaata (generated one) , SSO Circle throws the error saying **"An error occured. Reason:0004-Entity descriptor "localhost" under realm "%2F" has invalid syntax.**"

I don't know what exactly is the problem.
Help is needed :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that the property includeDiscoveryExtension is set to false on your MetadataGenerator bean. If it is set to true an Extensions element is generated which is not compatible with SSOCircle. Check that no extensions element is included in the generated metadata.

Comment: I didn't include the field at all (I assumed default value was false). I changed the entityId from local host to the one mentioned in security xml.Thanks for your info.